# Do I need to keep updating Armory version and more?

Tags: armory

Do I need to keep updating version of Armory when it notifies me of new version. Just wondering if these are security patches or just some new bells and whistles in new armory versions. Seems like it took me forever to DL Armory and to install a new version every few months seems like a huge pain I run linux so that makes it even more difficult because I have manually uninstall and re-install and my newbie self doesnt' even know how to on linux as there is no automated uninstall or install like windows.

What gives?

Comment: If you take a look at the *Patch Notes*, it will tell you the content of the patch. Then you can make an informed choice.

Answer (score 1):

It really boils down to fixes and any upcoming security issue which are announced with the releases, but in general it's a good idea to upgrade every once in a while (at least it will likely make any mandatory update less painful). The updates should usually be less painful than initial install - sometimes no database rebuilds are even needed, and v0.93 rebuild is very fast too.

Note that sooner or later you will eventually need to upgrade Bitcoin core too. It may be running seamlessly from within Armory but you can also choose to run it yourself as a standalone application - either way updates will be required eventually to pick up the latest changes in the network. Armory updates often comes along with Bitcoin core updates as it need to support any Bitcoin core database changes.

Also if you use an offline wallet, there are some limitations in the version delta you can have between online and offline wallets - Armory will normally warn you loud and clear about them.